# How to setObject without duplicate key in a NSMapTable?

Tags: objective-c

I am creating a NSMapTable with strong-strong reference for key and value. When I add different objects with same key, the key is getting duplicated. How to overwrite a key if exists?

```
NSMapTable *table = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory];
// ..
[table setObject:object forKey:key];
```

Currently I get a hash map like: `{"a" 1, "b" 2, "a" 3, "c" 1}`.

How to avoid duplicate keys?

Comment: Is the key a `NSString`?

Comment: No. It is a custom object.

Comment: Did you implement `isEqual:` and `hash`?

Comment: I had implemented those for the custom objects.

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. Not sure why it did not work before.